# Morphisms in a category with products

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm having a hard time proving that
$$(\psi\phi)\times(\psi\phi)=(\psi\times\psi)(\phi\times\phi),$$
where $\phi:G\to H$ and $\psi:H\to K$ in some category with products. I have seen a diagram of this (see below) and it seems straightforward. But I can't manage this computation it seems. How is it done?

[image: diagram]

Comment: Page 59 appears not to be included in the book preview, at least where I am. (Just so you know; it doesn't seem to be essential to the question).

Comment: @MattPressland: Ok, good to know in the future. Added a screenshot.

Comment: Do you understand why this diagram commutes? Almost all commutative squares are definitions.

Comment: @Oskar: I can't say I do with conviction...

Comment: @Carolus: I think you should look at the definition of the morphism $f\times g$, where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary morphisms in category with finite products. And remember, that all morphisms to a product determined by their projections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result holds much more generally.

I think that [this ProofWiki proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Product_of_Composite_Morphisms) (which I coincidentally provided to PW myself) will provide what you need (you can follow some links to see the definitions).

Normally, I would include the argument, but there is no support for drawing the diagrams here, which makes everything much less insightful.

---

As per request, an attempt to clarify commutation of the top "triangle" in OPs diagram.

By definition, the morphism $(\psi\phi)\times(\psi\phi)$ is the *unique* (by virtue of the definition of the categorical product) morphism $f: G \times G \to K \times K$ such that:

$$\pi^1_K f = (\psi\phi)\pi^1_G\qquad\text{and}\qquad\pi^2_K f = (\psi\phi)\pi^2_G$$

where $\pi^i_K: K \times K \to K$ and $\pi^i_G: G \times G \to G$, $i=1,2$ are the first and second projection morphisms from the product (which are signified by $m_G$ and $m_K$ in your diagram, dropping the $1$ and $2$ since they're "identical").

The commutation of the two middle squares implies that the perimeter of the resulting rectangle commutes as well, i.e. $m_K\left((\psi\times\psi)(\phi\times\phi)\right) = (\psi\phi)m_G$.

That is, $(\psi\times\psi)(\phi\times\phi)$ is a morphism fitting the definition of $(\psi\phi)\times(\psi\phi)$. Since there was only one such morphism, they must be equal, and the top "triangle" commutes.

Note that this is in essence the same proof as given on the ProofWiki page.

Comment: Ok, so it's enough to produce a "valid" diagram? Does my added diagram suffice as proof? (I'm very new to category theory and I'm kind of lost)

Comment: A diagram helps one to express ideas. A valid diagram can be fully decomposed into a lot of equations (with annoying invocations of transitivity etc.) and the nice thing about it is, that you only need to verify each "square" separately (this is where associativity kicks in). So after a while, it can serve as a proof, albeit somewhat an informal one (unless one actually verifies its commutation explicitly).

Comment: Ok, I've verified the "bottom part" of the above diagram symbolically, but my problem is the top part. Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: On my diagram...

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm beginning to understand now. The diagrams at ProofWiki were also helpful.

Comment: This is a nice example of a very general way to prove things in category theory; in order to show that two maps are equal, it is sufficient to show that both fit into the same universal diagram. Then they are equal by uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is far more easy just to compute things instead of drawing large diagrams(*). Recall that $\phi \times \psi$ is defined by $p_1 \circ (\phi \times \psi) = \phi \circ p_1$ and $p_2 \circ (\phi \times \psi)=\psi \circ p_2$.

Let $\phi_i : G_i \to H_i$ and $\psi : H_i \to K_i$ homomorphisms of groups for $i=1,2$. We claim that $(\psi_1  \times \psi_2)  \circ (\phi_1 \times \phi_2) = (\psi_1 \circ \phi_1) \times (\psi_2 \circ \phi_2)$ as morphisms $G_1 \times G_2 \to K_1 \times K_2$.

Proof: It suffices to check this after composing with the two projections.

$p_1 \circ (\psi_1  \times \psi_2)  \circ (\phi_1 \times \phi_2)
=\psi_1 \circ p_1 \circ (\phi_1 \times \phi_2)
=\psi_1 \circ \phi_1 \circ p_1
= p_1 \circ ((\psi_1 \circ \phi_1) \times (\psi_2 \circ \phi_2))$

Similarily for $p_2$, QED.

More generally, limits are functorial in the following sense: If $\{G_i\},\{H_i\},\{K_i\}$ are diagrams in a category, whose limits exist, and $\phi : \{G_i\} \to \{H_i\}$, $\psi : \{H_i\} \to \{K_i\}$ are morphisms of diagrams, then $\lim_i (\psi_i \circ \phi_i) = \lim_i \psi_i \circ \lim_i \phi_i$ as morphisms $\lim_i G_i \to \lim_i K_i$. The same proof as above works.

(*) I have already come across several papers on category theory such as the early ones by Anders Kock containing long (and nontrivial, not something as above) computations with 10 lines, which would fill two pages of diagrams instead.

Comment: What are $p_1$ and $p_2$? Where do these different subscripts come from?

Comment: $p_1,p_2$ are the projections (read the definition of a product first).

Comment: You might want to consider rewording your post and comment; I find them to be on the edge of condescension. ("far more easy", "nontrivial, not as above", "read the definition of product")

Comment: Thank you for your advice.